# How do I save new variables in Gitlab CI/CD from gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to the Ops world!

I am trying to deploy an application in Azure AKS, with Gitlab and terraform.

I am able to create AKS clusers by using gitlab-ci.yml file (running terraform files with Hashicorp image).

After the cluster is created, I would want to store the cluster details (host, client_certificate, client_Key and client_key_certificate), so that I can deploy applications and databases on that cluster.

Ideally, I need to save the output of terraform as environment variables in Gitlab CI/CD.

Please route me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found this doc from Gitlab to create variables using the API, which possibly will resolve my issue. Thanks

Comment: You should post that as an answer, linking to the documentation and summarising it so that it might help others (or yourself in 6 months time when you forget!).

Answer (score 1):

Found this doc from Gitlab to create variables using the API, which possibly will resolve my issue. Thanks

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html